# Logs in Weblogic on a server different than the admin server

Tags: logging, weblogic

I am very new to WebLogic.

I have a WebLogic domain in which there are 2 servers running one of which is the admin server and on both servers there are webservices that I am trying to test.

Whenever a request is sent to the url of the admin server, the output is showing in the server logs while when using that of the second server, nothing is showing although I configured the logging for both servers in the same way.

Appreciate any help.

***EDIT :***

Sorry I forgot to mention that I am using log4j for the webservices loggin

Comment: Can you please share the configurations on [WL web console]/Servers/[Your server]/Log ?
Also, go to your [WL home]/user_projects/domains/[your domain]/servers/[your server]/logs folder in the file system, as it is the default location.

Comment: Hi, well actually I am able to see the logs for the server, but not those of the webservices. Sorry maybe I should've mentioned that I'm using log4j

Comment: Ok. What about pasting your log4j configuration here? Also, check your deployment's log configuration. The problem might be there.

Answer (score 7):

As Viccari suggested, you should be able to find the logs in the following locations:

- Server 1 node(Admin Server) :

  ```
  [WL home]/user_projects/domains/[your domain]/servers/AdminServer/logs
  ```
- Server 2 node:

  ```
  [WL home]/user_projects/domains/[your domain]/servers/Server2_name/logs
  ```

Further, I would recommend starting the servers from the command-line and capture the output of those started processes into additional logging files, for example:

- For AdminServer:

  > [WL home]/user_projects/domains/[your domain]/startWeblogic.sh | tee log.AdminServer
- For Server2:

  > [WL home]/user_projects/domains/[your domain]/bin/startManagedWebLogic.sh server2_name t3://adminServer:7001 | tee log.server2_name

These logs will e.g. show you the output of `System.out.println()` called in your Webservices.

Also, have a look into the `[WL home]/user_projects/domains/[your domain]/bin/startWeblogic.sh` script and set the variable `WLS_REDIRECT_LOG` to a value pointing to a file where you want to store the Weblogic output.

Comment: Hi, well actually I am able to see the logs for the server, but not those of the webservices. Sorry maybe I should've mentioned that I'm using log4j